# Mule soap Proxy wsdl fails at relative path resolution of xsd

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, mule

I have a WSDL and a Mule SOAP proxy web service using the MuleSoft XML Only SOAP Web Service example. 
My application is working fine but if i enable validation i have one issue: When the XSD is stored anywhere other than the root of the project, it will not resolve. 
I created folders of service and xsd inside /src/main/resources, 
however when the service is invoked I receive the following error:

```
    connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.wstx_msv_validation.ResolvingGrammarReaderController: D:\Developer\Global\BODs\GetListSalesOrder.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Developer\Global\BODs\GetListSalesOrder.xsd (The system cannot find the path)
```

This is my mule flow..

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service port="SyncSalesOrderBinding" namespace="http://www.cg.com/services/oagis/salesOrder" service="SyncSalesOrderService" validationEnabled="true" payload="body" wsdlLocation="services/WebServices/WSDL/SalesOrder.wsdl" doc:name="CXF">
            <cxf:schemaLocations>
                <cxf:schemaLocation>services/Developer/Global/BODs/GetListSalesOrder.xsd</cxf:schemaLocation>
            </cxf:schemaLocations>
        </cxf:proxy-service>
        <logger message="Success" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: Which folder did you kept your xsd ? is it in /src/main/resources folder directly ?? Or did you created any folder inside /src/main/resources folder and then kept xsd under it ?

Comment: i have created folder in /src/main/resources..src/main/resources/services/Developer/Global/BODs/GetListSalesOrder.xsd

Comment: what is the name of the folder ?

Comment: src/main/resources/services/Developer/Global/BODs/GetListSa‌​lesOrder.xsd

Comment: what is your Mule Flow .. please update your question with your Mule config so that the issue can be resolved ..

Comment: check question now..i have update question.

Comment: yes.i have specify in wsdl location.

Comment: Please let me know the below solution worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XSD file is imported in your wsdl file the following Code is fine :-

```
<cxf:proxy-service port="SyncSalesOrderBinding" namespace="http://www.cg.com/services/oagis/salesOrder" service="SyncSalesOrderService" validationEnabled="true" payload="body" wsdlLocation="services/WebServices/WSDL/SalesOrder.wsdl" doc:name="CXF"/>
```

You don't need to mention your XSD file in CXF component .. it will **validate**

If you still face any issues then there is patch available here : https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5963?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

.... Please you replace your jar with the one attached to the JIRA ... It will work definately

Comment: hey bro..Its not working...actually i copied all xsd mannually at D drive..so xsd taken from that location..

Comment: I copied all the xsd's in D:\Developer\Global\BODs\...So all xsd taken from this location...i want all xsd's take automatically from Mule apps folder..

Comment: If you copy and paste your wsdl and xsd in main/resource folder it will work fine

Comment: Where did you kept your xsd and wsdl file ... give the full path here ... is your xsd and wsdl are in same path ?? if your xsd and wsdl are in same path .. in your wsdl you should import it from same path

Comment: No..then it give me exception..java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Developer\Global\BODs\GetListSalesOrder.xsd (The system cannot find the path)

Comment: see ... for example if your WSDL and XSD are in same path .. you should mention it in your WSDL import that it should import from the same path ... then when you copy your WSDL and XSD in main/resource folder then there also it should be in same path .. and in wsdlLocation="  you should mention the path of WSDL of resource folder

Comment: xsd and wsdl are in main/resource folder..xsd are in src/main/resource/services/Developer/Global/BODs/...and wsdl are in src/main/resource/services/WebServices/WSDL/..

Comment: You mention the path of xsd in WSDL import that it should take xsd from services/Developer/Global/BODs/ and in CXF component mention the path like <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="services/WebServices/WSDL/SalesOrder.wsdl" doc:name="CXF"/>

Comment: yes i mention same as you specify above..but it looks xsd at D:\Developer\Global\BODs\GetListSalesOrder.xsd...but actual path should be Source\.mule\apps\validation\classes\Developer\Global\BODs\GetListSalesOrder.xsd

Comment: Did you changed it in WSDL file also ?? Do one thing  .. keep both the files under main/resources folder directly... then in wsdl file modify the xsd import and mention schemaLocation="GetListSalesOrder.xsd" .. and then in CXF component modify the path like <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="SalesOrder.wsdl" doc:name="CXF"/> .... and at last before running the application build and clean it first

Comment: Remember both file should be at same location under main/resources folder directly

Comment: Suppose you have 3 xsd files ..a.xsd, b.xsd and c.cxd... copy all the xsd and wsdl file and paste it directly in resource folder (don't create any folder) .. all the files should be in same location .. Now after that open your wsdl and give the xsd path like :- import namespace="your namespace" schemaLocation="a.xsd" .. import namespace="your namespace" schemaLocation="b.xsd" and import namespace="your namespace" schemaLocation="c.xsd" .. (Don't mention any path there ) .. now mention your wsdl path in CXF like <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="SalesOrder.wsdl" doc:name="CXF"/>

Comment: Now clean and build and run